# How to get a list of all defined variables in less?

Tags: css, less

Is there any way within less to get the list of *all* variables defined within the current scope?

In the less code below I am creating a list `@variables` with one entry for each variable defined in `mixins/variables`.  When the number of variables in my file is updated my list must be as well.  Instead of a manually defined list I would like to access and output *every* defined variable.

```
@import "src/styles/css/mixins/for";
@import "src/styles/css/mixins/variables";

@variables: navy, darkBlueGrey, blueGrey, darkBlue;
#variables {
  .for(@variables); .-each(@value) {
    & when (ispixel(@@value)) {
      @{value}: unit(@@value);
    }
    & when not (ispixel(@@value)) {
      @{value}: @@value;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
#variables {
    "navy": "#2b3d49",
    "darkBlueGrey": "#334455",
    "blueGrey": "#516171",
    "darkBlue": "#1c5577"
}
```

(I know this snippet is neither valid CSS nor JSON.  There are further processing steps done on this output to format it correctly.)

(The for loop mixin is defined [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/master/src/for.less).)